# mbed uvisor and EthernetInterface overflowed

Tags: c, mbed

I am quite new to mbed and uvisor so maybe my problem is about understanding how things work. I have a NXP FRDM-K64F board where I am trying to learn about mbed and uvisor. I have succesfully compiled an run some basic examples of tasks running on different boxes. I am trying to connect to the net one of the boxes in uvisor but something is not working correctly.

This is the main file code:

```
#include "uvisor-lib/uvisor-lib.h"
#include "mbed.h"
#include "main-hw.h"

/* Create ACLs for main box. */
MAIN_ACL(g_main_acl);

/* Enable uVisor. */
UVISOR_SET_MODE_ACL(UVISOR_ENABLED, g_main_acl);
UVISOR_SET_PAGE_HEAP(8 * 1024, 5);

int main(void)
{
    printf("----Eup---------\r\n");
    DigitalOut led(MAIN_LED);

    while (1) {
        printf("taka\r\n");
        led = !led;

        /* Blink once per second. */
        Thread::wait(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code in box file:

```
#include "uvisor-lib/uvisor-lib.h"
#include "mbed.h"
#include "main-hw.h"
#include "EthernetInterface.h"

// Network interface
EthernetInterface net;

struct box_context {
    Thread * thread;
    uint32_t heartbeat;
};

static const UvisorBoxAclItem acl[] = {
};

static void my_box_main(const void *);

/* Box configuration
 * We need 1kB of stack both in the main and interrupt threads as both of them
 * use printf. */
UVISOR_BOX_NAMESPACE(NULL);
UVISOR_BOX_HEAPSIZE(3072);
UVISOR_BOX_MAIN(my_box_main, osPriorityNormal, 1024);
UVISOR_BOX_CONFIG(my_box, acl, 1024, box_context);


static void my_box_main(const void *)
{

    while (1) {
        printf("tan tan\r\n");
        Thread::wait(2000);
    }

}
```

I have not yet added the specific connection code, just the definition of the EthernetInterface object and I am getting the following error on compilation:

```
../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: Region m_data_2 overflowed with stack and heap
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have tried changing the values of the heap size but I have not found a way of making it work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main box, change the value for `UVISOR_SET_PAGE_HEAP`.

With `UVISOR_SET_PAGE_HEAP(8 * 1024, 3)` in the main box; and 8K heap in the secure box and `UVISOR_BOX_STACK_SIZE` stack size in the secure box it compiles and links for me (mbed OS 5.3, GCC ARM on K64F).